# Redeclaring a function inside a function

Tags: c++

I stumbled across a strange c++ snippet. I consider this as bad code. Why would someone repeat the function declaration inside a function? It even compiles when changing the type signature to `unsigned int sum(int, int)` producing the expected result 4294967294j. Why does this even compile?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int sum(int, int); // redeclaring sum???
    int a = -1;
    auto result = sum(a, a);
    cout << result << typeid(result).name() << endl;
}
```

Edit: It compiles for me... but is it valid C++ code? If not why does the compiler (mingw 4.8.1) allow it?

Comment: You can declare stuff as many time as you want, believe it or not... `int sum(int,int); int sum(int,int); int sum(int,int); int sum(int,int);` is valid C++, and needs to be to allow for forward declaration to be allowable. What doesn't make sense to me is the type change not only being OK, but isn't selecting a different name...

Comment: Even more bizzare, you can move the definition of the function below main, and the declaration of sum in main can return a non-int-castable struct, and then you can call `aa ss = sum(d,e);` AND IT COMPILES AND RUNS.

Comment: Change the return type of local declaration to `float` and you get [weird results.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46262f2c84031c9c) I'd say that this violates ODR rule.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is forward declaring, because it is inside a function and can alter the type signature. Maybe it's some old c-relict.

Comment: @Markus that is a declaration, and changing the return type isn't valid.

Comment: @j That result is what I would expect. The _return type of a function is not part of its signature_, unlike its parameters. Since `float sum(...)` shadows `int sum(...)`, the type of `result` is inferred as `float`. But when the linker looks for `sum(int, int)`, it ignores the return type, and links `int` version since it's the only definition available. The way returning a value works on x86 is the `int` is put into a specific register. The caller copies that register as-is into `result`, effectively reinterpreting the `float` as `int`. In general this is almost certainly UB and non-portable.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Your supported by http://ideone.com/s1VbKC, which is freakin bizzarre...This seems like a good way to write buggy code.

Comment: @Mad Welcome to the wonderful world of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes there is a sense to redeclare a function inside a block scope. For example if you want to set a default argument. Consider the following code

```
#include <typeinfo>

using namespace std;

int sum(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int sum(int, int = -1 ); // redeclaring sum???
    int a = -1;
    auto result = sum(a, a);
    cout << result << typeid(result).name() << endl;

    result = sum(a);
    cout << result << typeid(result).name() << endl;
}
```

Another case is when you want to call a concrete function from a set of overloaded functions. Consider the following example

```
#include <iostream>

void g( int ) { std::cout << "g( int )" << std::endl; }
void g( short ) { std::cout << "g( short )" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
   char c = 'c';
   g( c );

   {
      void g( short );
      g( c );
   }
}
```

Comment: That is useful, although a tad nasty.

Comment: that second case is much better handled by casting the argument(s). This last bit is very nasty `;-)`

Comment: @rubenvb Sometimes casting looks bad especially when a function has many arguments.

Comment: that would be intentional. Redeclaring the function delocalizes this cast from the call size, and might hide a bug when the different function overloads mix.

Answer (score 2):

If that's the actual code, there's no reason to do it.

If the function `sum` is defined somewhere else though, the declaration inside `main` makes it accessible only inside `main`. You can't use it anywhere else in that translation unit (unless of course you declare it). So it's a sort of limiting visibility to where it's needed, but, granted, it's not very readable.

Regarding changing the return type - that's illegal. You're not seeing any issues with `unsigned int`, but if you try

```
char sum(int, int); // redeclaring sum???
```

you'll see there's a problem there.

Comment: @Jarod42 a return type isn't part of the signature. Also, that's illegal.

Comment: Why redeclaring outside function fail to compile whereas redeclaring inside function succeeds compilation (https://ideone.com/1T91Bi) ?

Comment: @Jarod42 For the same reason why (in a function) `{ extern int i; extern short i; }` fails, whereas `{ extern int i; { extern short i; } }` is accepted. Incompatible declarations are diagnosed at compile time if the declarations have the same scope.